# In R, is there any way to automatically run an output after it has been printed?

Tags: r

Sorry if this sounds a bit messy, I'm new to using R. I have a data frame named "AB13" ( a postcode) and I am using a list of all postcodes which I imported as a .csv file. Is there any way I can print one of the columns and run it through the console automatically. Say print the 10th element of the list, which is AB13. Then it will display AB13 ( the data frame)?

I have tried using print, cat and multiple other print functions but I haven't been able to get anywhere.

Comment: So for some more background, when I run cat on the 10th line, I get AB13, but I don't know how to get the data frame that is returned when I write AB13 directly into the console.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
 get(your_list[[10]])
```

Comment: Thank you! That was perfect.